# MongoDB IAM Authentication : Cannot Authenticate using IAM Roles

Tags: mongodb, amazon-web-services, amazon-iam

I am unable to authenticate using IAM roles which are added to the cluster.
Currently, There is a Role created and attached with the Ec2 instance. Using the same role while connecting to the DB and running any command. I am getting the following error.

```
    error: {
"operationTime" : Timestamp(1635767862, 1),
"ok" : 0,
"errmsg" : "command find requires authentication",
"code" : 13,
"codeName" : "Unauthorized",
"$clusterTime" : {
"clusterTime" : Timestamp(1635767862, 1),
"signature" : {
"hash" : BinData(0,"WibtM8VK2aorci9mA6QNyP/ummU="),
"keyId" : NumberLong("7023742477949468676")
}
}
}
```

Has anyone ever faced any issue like this with IAM roles and MongoDB Atlas mongo?